# Real-time Proxy Suggestions?

Tags: web-applications, proxy, reverse-proxy, real-time, server-sent-events

We are building a web app in React.js. We intend for it (the frontend) to maintain a persistent connection through which it will receive server-sent events to update its state. But we also want it so scale well horizontally. So our backend must be stateless.

What we need is something to bridge the gap between our frontend and backend. Something that manages the persistent frontend connections and allows the backend to call it in order to dispatch server-sent events.

So far we found one candidate that would solve this problem. The commercial solution is called [Fanout](https://fanout.io/) and the open source variant (which appears to be hard to scale) is named [Pushpin](https://pushpin.org/). They are marketed as "Real-time proxies".

I find it hard to believe that these are the only solutions to what seems to be quite a common problem. We would like to explore alternatives. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Pushpin lead dev (and Fanout founder) here, so I am biased.

> We would like to explore alternatives. Any suggestions?

As someone watching this space, at the time of this writing (March 2021), I believe the closest alternatives to Pushpin are:

- [AWS API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api-overview.html). This only supports WebSockets (not SSE or other HTTP-based streams), but it appears to do it in a generic way. It can probably be used to implement arbitrary WebSocket API definitions.
- [Nchan](https://nchan.io/). This offers some proxy-like behavior, though its API schema is somewhat opinionated. It can probably be used to implement some HTTP/WebSocket API definitions, but not arbitrary ones.

> I find it hard to believe that these are the only solutions to what seems to be quite a common problem

This often surprises me too. I think it can be explained by the fact that realtime API development tends to be pretty gnarly and involve opinionated decisions. Developers are usually concerned about meeting the requirements of the company they work at, not making their solution portable to the requirements of other companies. And solving this problem in a general way is non-obvious.

For example, Uber [recently wrote](https://eng.uber.com/real-time-push-platform/) about their realtime platform, but they don't make the solution available to others, and even if they did it would be so full of Uber-isms as to be unusable to anyone else. At best you could take some of their ideas and build your own realtime platform that only your company will be able to use. ;)